# Where should I write controller logic that combines two models

Tags: php, laravel, orm

Imagine I have PostController and CommentController, of course I have Post model and Comment model. So now I receive request to make some modifications for both Post and Comment model (maybe this modification logic combines not only two models but 3, 4, 5 or even more), so It shouldn't be right to write logic In Post or Comment controllers. So where should I write  this logic? should I make new controller?

Comment: You can even create classes that holds common logic.

Comment: yes I know, but I am just interested what is the best practice

Answer (score 1):

You must try the repository pattern.

The idea of this pattern is to separe the layer of logic from the controllers, every model has a repository with his logic, also every logic layer, every repo, can have another layer to hold the queries to the DB (a database layer).

Then you can insert that repositories in the controllers, trough dependency injection in the constructor of each one, you'll have less code in the controllers, the logic is more testeable, and you can share the logic in more than one controller without repeating it.

Check at this posts:

- https://medium.com/@jsdecena/refactor-the-simple-tdd-in-laravel-a92dd48f2cdd
- https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/

Answer (score 0):

you should use relationships in my opinion. 
Please check documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

You can then easy access and update both using one Controller.

Comment: yes I know about relationships quite well but you can't  manage everything by relationships. I am not talking only about Post and Comment. I am talking about big and complicated project example

Comment: I think you can use relationships as long as you have any relation between your Models. I've done simple app which also includes 3 relations, so when I update 1st Model it goes trought relation to another and then to the 3rd one + creates logs